# Pympler summary doesn't seem to make sense

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I'm doing some sanity checks with Pympler to make sure that I understand results when I try to profile an actual script, but I'm a bit puzzled at the results. Here are the sanity checks I've tried:

SANITY CHECK 1: I fire up a Python (3) console and do the following:

```
from pympler import summary, muppy
sum = summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects())
summary.print_(sum)
```

This results in the following summary:

```
                               types |   # objects |   total size
==================================== | =========== | ============
                         <class 'str |       16047 |      1.71 MB
                        <class 'dict |        2074 |      1.59 MB
                        <class 'type |         678 |    678.27 KB
                        <class 'code |        4789 |    673.68 KB
                         <class 'set |         464 |    211.00 KB
                        <class 'list |        1319 |    147.16 KB
                       <class 'tuple |        1810 |    120.03 KB
                     <class 'weakref |        1269 |     99.14 KB
          <class 'wrapper_descriptor |        1124 |     87.81 KB
  <class 'builtin_function_or_method |         918 |     64.55 KB
                 <class 'abc.ABCMeta |          64 |     62.25 KB
           <class 'method_descriptor |         877 |     61.66 KB
                         <class 'int |        1958 |     58.88 KB
           <class 'getset_descriptor |         696 |     48.94 KB
                 function (__init__) |         306 |     40.64 KB
```

If I've just fired up a new Python session, how are there all these strings, dictionaries, lists etc. in memory already? I don't think that Pympler is summarizing the results across all sessions (that would make no sense, but it's the only possibility I could think of).

SANITY CHECK 2: Since I don't quite understand the summary results of a tabula rasa Python session, let's look at the difference in summary after I've defined a few variables/data structures. I fire up another console and do the following:

```
from pympler import summary, muppy
sum = summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects())
a = {}
b = {}
c = {}
d = {'a': [0, 0, 1, 2], 't': [3, 3, 3, 1]}
sum1 = summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects())
summary.print_(summary.get_diff(sum, sum1))
```

This results in the following summary:

```
                         types |   # objects |   total size
============================== | =========== | ============
                  <class 'list |        3247 |    305.05 KB
                   <class 'str |        3234 |    226.04 KB
                   <class 'int |         552 |     15.09 KB
                  <class 'dict |           1 |    480     B
              function (_keys) |           0 |      0     B
           function (get_path) |           0 |      0     B
          function (http_open) |           0 |      0     B
            function (memoize) |           0 |      0     B
                function (see) |           0 |      0     B
           function (recvfrom) |           0 |      0     B
              function (rfind) |           0 |      0     B
      function (wm_focusmodel) |           0 |      0     B
    function (_parse_makefile) |           0 |      0     B
  function (_decode_pax_field) |           0 |      0     B
             function (__gt__) |           0 |      0     B
```

I thought I'd just initialized four new dictionaries (albeit 3 are empty), so why does Muppy show a difference of only 1 new dictionary object? Furthermore, why are there thousands of new strings and lists, not to mention the ints?

SANITY CHECK 3: Yet again, I start a new Python session but this time want to see how Pympler handles more complex data types like a list of dictionaries.

```
from pympler import muppy, summary
sum = summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects())
a = [{}, {}, {}, {'a': [0, 0, 1, 2], 't': [3, 3, 3, 1]}, {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}]
sum1 = summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects())
summary.print_(summary.get_diff(sum, sum1))
```

Which results in the following summary:

```
                                                types |   # objects |   total size
===================================================== | =========== | ============
                                         <class 'list |        3233 |    303.88 KB
                                          <class 'str |        3270 |    230.71 KB
                                          <class 'int |         554 |     15.16 KB
                                         <class 'dict |          10 |      5.53 KB
                                         <class 'code |          16 |      2.25 KB
                                         <class 'type |           2 |      1.98 KB
                                        <class 'tuple |           6 |    512     B
                            <class 'getset_descriptor |           4 |    288     B
                                  function (__init__) |           2 |    272     B
  <class '_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader |           3 |    168     B
                 <class '_frozen_importlib.ModuleSpec |           3 |    168     B
                                      <class 'weakref |           2 |    160     B
                                  function (__call__) |           1 |    136     B
                                      function (Find) |           1 |    136     B
                                  function (<lambda>) |           1 |    136     B
```

Even though the lists and dictionaries are nested a bit convoluted, by my count I added 5 new dictionaries and four new lists.

Can someone explain how Muppy is counting objects?

Comment: Good question! I am getting started with muppy and have similar questions popping up in my head :-?

Comment: No replies. *Sigh*

Answer (score 2):

## 1 `get_objects` in a new Python session

`summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects())` returns any objects instantiated during the startup and while `from pympler import summary, muppy` ran, which explains the large counts.

## 2 The difference between two `get_objects` invocations

### 2.1. Lots of new objects we didn't create

Remember that the `sum` object generated by `summary.summarize()` was created after the first snapshot, which explains "thousands of new strings and lists". You can fix this by rewriting your test as:

```
from pympler import summary, muppy
o1 = muppy.get_objects()
a = {}
b = {}
c = {}
d = {'a': [0, 0, 1, 2], 't': [3, 3, 3, 1]}
o2 = muppy.get_objects()
summary.print_(summary.get_diff(summary.summarize(o1), summary.summarize(o2)))
```

This will reduce the extraneous diffs to the large list for `o1`, and a couple of other objects:

```
>>> for o in diff['+']:
...     print("%s - %s" % (type(o), o if len(o) < 10 else "long list"))
...
<class 'str'> - o2
<class 'list'> - long list
<class 'dict'> - {'a': [0, 0, 1, 2], 't': [3, 3, 3, 1]}
<class 'list'> - ['o2', 'muppy', 'get_objects']
<class 'list'> - [0, 0, 1, 2]
<class 'list'> - [3, 3, 3, 1]
```

### 2.2. The mismatch in the number of dicts created and reported

To understand this, we need to know what exactly pympler is inspecting.

`muppy.get_objects` implementation [relies](https://github.com/pympler/pympler/blob/97610ee48f04be0fbe09ffed0b574f3a763ecd52/pympler/muppy.py#L20) on

- Python's `gc.get_objects()`, which is "a list of all objects tracked by the collector" ([`gc.is_tracked`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.is_tracked)), except stack frames.

  > instances of atomic types aren’t tracked and instances of non-atomic types (containers, user-defined objects…) are. However, some type-specific optimizations can be present in order to suppress the garbage collector footprint of simple instances (e.g. **dicts containing only atomic keys and values**)
- Then it adds the objects that are referred ([gc.get_referents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referents)) from the objects obtained at step 1, but [excluding](https://github.com/pympler/pympler/blob/97610ee48f04be0fbe09ffed0b574f3a763ecd52/pympler/muppy.py#L47) "container objects" - those that have [Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC) in their type's `__flags__`. (This seems to be a bug, since excluding all container objects misses the "simple instances" of container types, that are not GC-tracked. **update** [Should be fixed](https://github.com/pympler/pympler/commit/62df1f5ba695b2ddebf3612f2307b5527c16800f) in v0.8 released 2019-11-12)

If you store the object list `o2` as suggested above and check which objects are accounted for using:

```
def tracked(obj_list, obj):
    import gc
    return {"tracked_by_muppy": any(id(item) == id(obj) for item in obj_list),
            "gc_tracked": gc.is_tracked(obj)}
```

You'll see that:

- Empty dicts are not GC-tracked and as they are only referred to from local variables, they are not accounted for by muppy:

  ```
    tracked(o2, a)  # => {'tracked_by_muppy': False, 'gc_tracked': False}
  ```
- The non-trivial dict `d` *is* GC-tracked and thus appears in muppy report:

  ```
    tracked(o2, d)  # => {'tracked_by_muppy': True, 'gc_tracked': True}
  ```